# *-tag, *_tag not working in scss deployed in heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass

I have this in one of my apps scss file: `background: image_url('loading.gif') 0 0 no-repeat;` It works on my local machine giving me `url(...)` but when I deploy it in heroku it renders as `image_url(...)`.

I'm using a cedar stack according to `heroku info`

Answer (score 0):

In deployment, Filename and extensions are case sensitive. so check your filename.